# Android Google Maps V2 Info Windows

Tags: android

I have today just started a very basic Android application which contains a simple Google Map and a few markers added with the following code:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat, lon)
    .title("Name")
    .snippet("Address")
); // end marker.
```

What I notice from this, is when you click on the marker on the map, the infowindow opens automatically. My question is, where do I put the code to execute on opening of the infowindow? Ideally, I need it so that when you click a button or something inside the infowindow to say "More information" a new screen comes up providing full information.

In the past and with other applications, I simply added a listener to the object concerned then when it was clicked, the corresponding onClick() method was called but due to the nature of the automatic infowindow here, this isn't the case!

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally, I need it so that when you click a button or something inside the infowindow to say "More information" a new screen comes up providing full information.

That is not possible. You can respond to taps on the entire info window (`setOnInfoWindowClickListener()`), though.

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried this too but which object would you apply setOnInfoWindowClickListener() to? My guess is it would be map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener()?

Comment: @Jonathan: Correct, `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` is a method on `GoogleMap`.

Comment: That's the issue as that's the code that I have and just a simple print line inside the listener method which never prints no matter which infowindow you click or where abouts in it you click!

Comment: @Jonathan: Here is a sample project showing (among other things) responding to `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Taps

Comment: Thanks very much, I will take a look. This has been troubling me for some time now why I can't get the listener to fire! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same code this morning compared with yesterday morning and without any changes it just works! Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use an OnMarkerClickListener to listen for click events on the
>   marker. To set this listener on the map, call
>   GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(OnMarkerClickListener). When a user
>   clicks on a marker, onMarkerClick(Marker) will be called and the
>   marker will be passed through as an argument. This method returns a
>   boolean that indicates whether you have consumed the event (i.e., you
>   want to suppress the default behavior). If it returns false, then the
>   default behavior will occur in addition to your custom behavior. The
>   default behavior for a marker click event is to show its info window
>   (if available) and move the camera such that the marker is centered on
>   the map.
>
> You can use an OnInfoWindowClickListener to listen to click events on
>   an info window. To set this listener on the map, call
>   GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(OnInfoWindowClickListener).
>   When a user clicks on an info window, onInfoWindowClick(Marker) will
>   be called and the info window will be highlighted in the default
>   highlight color (Holo Blue for devices running Ice Cream Sandwich and
>   newer, orange for earlier versions of Android).
>
> As mentioned in the previous section on info windows, an info window
>   is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the
>   map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded
>   and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of
>   the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such
>   as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info
>   window.

Taken straight from the docs here:-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events

Comment: well you'd need to pass a variable of type OnMarkerClickListner in. E.g. myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); Then let your class implement OnMarkerClickListener

Comment: This doesn't actually work as it never actually goes into the listener method! I have map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); then later on @Override
 public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
  System.out.println("Hello World");
 } but the code never goes in here despite clicking the infowindow.

Comment: Works fine for me. I assume your map is ready (i.e. not null). Would need to see more code of how you've instantiated the map, and setup the listener.

Comment: Just seen your mistake, unless its a typo. setOnMarkerClickListener() will fire onMarkerClick(), not onInfoWindowClick() as above. It's setOnInfoWindowClickListener() that will fire onInfoWindowClick().

Comment: Sorry Ryan, that was just a typing mistake, the corresponding method is public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) which I assume map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); would fire? Does the map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); like have to be after all the pins have been added, before or does it not matter?

Comment: FYI I do it before markers are added and it still works fine.

Comment: I've moved the line to about every single line in the code and still it doesn't fire the event for some reason.